# BigQuery GA multiple values

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to isolate users that have two values for a field `([hits.customVariables.index])` within the same session in GA.

I suspect there is a much easier way of doing this; so please let me know if you know how.

For example, in the sql below, all of the sessions return '2', except the last one (returns 1) for the 'matches' field.

```
SELECT CONCAT([fullVisitorId] AS [column_A], STRING([visitId])) AS [Session],
(MAX(IF(SUM(CASE WHEN [hits.customVariables.index] IN (3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0,1,0)) + 
MAX(IF(SUM(CASE WHEN [hits.customVariables.index] IN (46) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0,1,0))) 
AS [matches]
FROM FLATTEN([1271835.ga_sessions_20141216], [hits.customVariables.index])
WHERE CONCAT([fullVisitorId], STRING([visitId])) IN 
('50956211505979902631418751704',
 '86512166255567372671418771317',
 '79580299450214242591418749991',
 '274962317238452051418783657')
GROUP BY [Session]
```

OUTPUT is here:

```
column_A  Session                         matches    
1         274962317238452051418783657       1    
2         50956211505979902631418751704     2    
3         86512166255567372671418771317     2    
4         79580299450214242591418749991     2
```

Comment: This change (above) is incorrect because it is the combination of fullVisitorId and Session that is unique.  Can we revert it to my original post?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for an alternate way to calculate "matches"?

If so, you can use nested SELECTs. An inner select to grab the sessions you want, then a middle select to filter down to the repeated index values to those you are interested in, and an outer select to sum up the matches.

The following should work for you:

```
SELECT
  Session,
  COUNT(hits.customVariables.index) AS match
FROM (
  SELECT
    Session,
    hits.customVariables.index
  FROM (
    SELECT
      CONCAT([fullVisitorId], STRING([visitId])) AS [Session],
      hits.customVariables.index
    FROM
      [1271835.ga_sessions_20141216]
    WHERE
      CONCAT([fullVisitorId], STRING([visitId])) IN
      ('50956211505979902631418751704',
        '86512166255567372671418771317',
        '79580299450214242591418749991',
        '274962317238452051418783657')
      )
  -- Drop index values we don't care about
  OMIT [hits.customVariables.index] IF
    NOT [hits.customVariables.index] IN (3, 46)
  -- Drop duplicates so we get a COUNT of unique values
  GROUP BY
    Session,
    hits.customVariables.index
    )
GROUP BY
  Session
```

If you want to limit the output to rows with match > 1, you can add the following around either query:

```
SELECT Session, match FROM (
  ...
  )
WHERE match > 1
```

Comment: This is a cool suggestion Michael, thanks!  only it looks even more complicated than what I am currently using.  I am pretty new to Bigquery so though that since these tables were denormalized there might just be some function or method to analyze separate occurrences (Flatten maybe?) of a child event without the weird Max/Case stuff I am using. In fact, I don't even need flatten in my original query, above. So, this works but I just can't believe it's how it is supposed to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure if you are looking to limit it to certain variable indexes and/or certain sessionIDs.

This is an example where I have limited it

```
SELECT 
  fullVisitorId, 
  CONCAT([fullVisitorId], STRING([visitId])) as sessionId,
COUNT( DISTINCT customDimensions.index, 100000 ) as unique_count
FROM [86276908.ga_sessions_20150109]
WHERE fullVisitorId IN ('947763264111444','505145409379903', '6201048528944990204')
AND customDimensions.index IN (1,2)
GROUP BY 
  fullVisitorId, 
  sessionId
HAVING unique_count > 1
```

Or it will work as follows if you want all visitors that had at least 2 different custom variables in a sessions

```
SELECT 
  fullVisitorId, 
  CONCAT([fullVisitorId], STRING([visitId])) as sessionId,
COUNT( DISTINCT customDimensions.index, 100000 ) as unique_count
FROM [86276908.ga_sessions_20150109]
GROUP BY 
  fullVisitorId, 
  sessionId
HAVING unique_count > 1
```

Comment: thanks, being pretty new to BigQuery I was just wondering if there was an easy way to count sessions where two specific actions were performed.  Even if a visitor performed them many times during a session I wanted to count that only once.  What I wrote does it but it just seemed odd to me that this would be the way it worked.

Comment: Great to hear your code was working and you were just looking for alternatives. Initially it does seem like things are over complicated but I feel you soon realise that it gives you more power